# Set notification URI for phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to set the correct URI for a custom sound in a phonegap app. I have tried several combinations including the following but I keep getting a `Uri cannot be resolved`

```
  notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://package_name/raw/notification/alarm.WAV");

  notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://package_name/raw/notification/");

  notif.sound = Uri.parse("file://path/to/file/alarm.WAV");
```

How do I set the Uri for a sound when using phonegap

**More info**

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html) at the end of which it explains how to add notifications from a push message....

```
  String message = extras.getString("message");
  String title = extras.getString("title");
  Notification notif = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, message,             System.currentTimeMillis() );
  notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
  notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestSampleApp.class);
  notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
  String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
  context.getSystemService(ns);
  mNotificationManager.notify(1, notif);
```

I thought removing `Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;` and adding the `uri` would make it place a custom sound.

Answer (score 0):

If that's JavaScript code, the problem is with the code and how you defined the Uri variable/library.

If you are using the `notification` API, there's no way to specify the [default "beep" sound](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.beep) (except for iOS, but that's because there isn't a beep sound on iOS.)

If you are trying to play a specific sound, I think you should be using the [media API.](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play) You can specify a sound to play like this:

```
function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: "+err);
    });

    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

Take a look at the "full example" to see how to set up the HTML page correctly.

Comment: This is java, from within a push plugin

Comment: Are you writing your own plugin? I need to see more code, I don't really have any idea what `notif` object is.

Comment: apologies more info in the question